# How to Test void Method with spring repository using Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking

i have a java spring service that call a spring data repository and i want to do a Junit test with mockito , this is my class and the service that i want to test :

```
@Service
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService{

    @Autowired
    private CautionRepository cautionRepository;



        @Override
        public void addCautions(List<CautionsDTO> cautions, Contrat contrat) {

            if(cautions != null && !cautions.isEmpty()) {
                cautions.forEach(caution -> {

                        Caution caution = new Caution();

                        cautionContrat.setAmount(caution.getAmount());
                        cautionContrat.setDate(caution.getDate());

                        caution.setContrat(contrat);

                        cautionRepository.save(caution);
            });
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my Unit test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DataServiceImplTest{

@InjectMocks
private DataServiceImpl dataService;

@Mock
private CautionRepository cautionRepository;

    @Test
    public void addListCautionsTest() {

        List<CautionsDTO> cautions = new ArrayList<>(); 
        ContratExportation contrat = new ContratExportation();

        Caution caution = new Caution();

         dataDelService.addCautions(cautions,contrat);

        Mockito.verify(cautionRepository, times(1)).save(caution);

    }
}
```

When i run the test i got the folowwing error :

```
Wanted but not invoked:
cautionRepository.save(
    org.model.Caution@2abe9173
);
-> at org.service.DataServiceImplTest.addListCautionsTest(DataServiceImplTest.java:292)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Do you have any idea please what is the mistake with my test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add a value to `cautions` so the loop is not executed and verify must fail.

Add a value to the list and the test should pass:

```
    List<CautionsDTO> cautions = new ArrayList<>(); 
    ContratExportation contrat = new ContratExportation();

    CautionDTO caution = new CautionDTO();
    cautions.add(caution);
    dataDelService.addCautions(cautions,contrat);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the correct code for executing the test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DataServiceImplTest{

@Autowired
private DataServiceImpl dataService;

@MockBean
private CautionRepository cautionRepository;

    @Test
    public void addListCautionsTest() {

        List<CautionsDTO> cautions = new ArrayList<>(); 
        ContratExportation contrat = new ContratExportation();

        Caution caution = new Caution();

         dataDelService.addCautions(cautions,contrat);

        Mockito.verify(cautionRepository, times(1)).save(caution);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you forgot to add *caution* object into *cautions* list. But other than that you are mixing Unit test with Integration test.

You need to annotate your test class with **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)**,

or

You need to annotate your mock objects with **@MockBean** and add @Autowired to your test class DataServiceImpl object.

Now, let me explain to you.

> Unit Test

When you want to write a unit test, you should **not make use of** application context (autowiring).

By the way, a better approach is to annotate your DataServiceImpl with @RequiredArgsConstructor from Lombok and remove @Autowired from CautionRepository. This will allow you to instantiate DataServiceImpl in a setup method in your unit test.

Your DataServiceImpl class should be:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService{

    private final CautionRepository cautionRepository;

    @Override
    public void addCautions(List<CautionsDTO> cautions, Contrat contrat) {
        // your code...
    }
}
```

and your new unit test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DataServiceImplTest{

    private DataServiceImpl dataService;

    @Mock
    private CautionRepository cautionRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        dataService = new DataServiceImpl(cautionsRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void addListCautionsTest() {
        // your test code...
    }
}
```

> Integration Test

Now, if you want to **create an integration test**, use **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)**. By doing this your application context will be loaded. In your case you can create a mocked bean inside your context by annotating your object with **@MockBean**. This will inject mocked object into your context and it will get auto wired in your real class.

For this your new DataServiceImpl class can remain same as above. But change your integration test into:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DataServiceImplTest{

    @Autowired
    private DataServiceImpl dataService;

    @MockBean // it will be injected automatically
    private CautionRepository cautionRepository;

    @Test
    public void addListCautionsTest() {
        // your test code...
    }
}
```

Hope, you now understand the difference and the mistake you were doing :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)